# How to implement Decorator pattern for Android views

Tags: android, design-patterns, decorator, android-custom-view

*NOTE: the actual question(s) is in the `What my questions are` section. The other sections are provided for giving better overview of the problem.*

***TASK***

I want to decorate Android view using the [Decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). For my question I will be using decorating [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) as an example, but I believe the solution will be more general.

***WHY DO I NEED IT***

I want to be able to reuse different augmentations on the standard views in different solutions of mine. E.g. now I have timer-switching `ViewPager` and `ViewPager` that notifies me when the user reaches its end. With this solution I am aiming at adding auto-switching notifying `ViewPager` (i.e. combining both my current extensions) in my next solution a one-liner. Decorator pattern is exactly for that.

***WHAT MY CURRENT APPROACH IS***

- I already wrapped the targeted `ViewPager` in `ViewPagerDecorator`
- I also did the desired extensions of the decorator - `AutoSwitchViewPager` and `NotifyOutOfBoundsViewPager` (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346824/viewpager-detect-when-user-is-trying-to-swipe-out-of-bounds)). Now I can even do

  `new AutoSwitchViewPager(new NotifyOutOfBoundsViewPager(viewPager))`.
- Now I am trying to figure out how to place this run-time created view in the layout. I am currently trying to figure out if I can replace ordinary `ViewPager` from layout propagating its xml attributes to the decorated view.

***WHAT MY QUESTIONS ARE***

- Is there a way to copy over the xml attributes from a layout-defined view to runtime constructed one (`LayoutParameters` at least)
- An alternative would be to use [`ViewStub`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html), but I did not find a way to inflate `ViewStub` with something completely run-time constructed (without using xml Layout). Is there such a way?

***WHAT HAVE I READ***

I have stumbled upon these related resources:

- [Decorating Android views](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/08/applying-decorator-pattern-to-decorate-views-on-android.html) - this is not entirely decorating the views in the sense that the decorator would not subscribe to the different events of the view. The decoration needs to be triggered by a special trigger method. However, the decorations I aim for truly need to act as full extensions of the decorated class.
- [Decorator pattern Android](https://deansserver.co.uk/~dean/2013/01/27/decorator-pattern-android/) - Here the decoration is again triggered via special method
- [Decorating an Android activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844981/android-cant-apply-decorator-pattern-on-activities) - with all the respect I have for ComonsWare I am very far away from questioning his statement. On the other hand, I believe that the views in Android allow you for more runtime modifications than the activities, so I still my case is plausible.

Comment: read about LayoutImflater.setFactory/LayoutImflater.setFactory2

Comment: LayoutInflater.Factory2 is better as it provides additional `View parent` parameter but it requires API 11+

Comment: just forgot to add that when implementing LayoutInflater.Factory2 in your Activity make sure you call super implementation

Comment: @pskink thanks for all the comments I am currently exploring this new possibility you pointed me to. Thanks you for giving me a direction!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After weeks of struggle and applying few different design approaches I think that I finally got the solution! As the solution is not as easy to explain as to fit in SO post I created a [blog post](http://bstrandjev.blogspot.com/2014/11/decorating-android-views.html) to explain all my struggles. I also accompany my explanations with source code to demonstrate my ideas available [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdg-sofia-prototypes/source/browse/#git%2Fdecorating_views).

Comment: Is your solution still current in Material Design's ViewPager two years later?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky If you are asking me whether the `ViewPager`'s new concepts are incorporated in the source code I provide - I believe it is rather not. However, the purpose of the question and the answer as well is to present rather a general approach, than particular `ViewPager` bound solution, though the latter is used as POC.

Comment: hi @BorisStrandjev I know it's an old question and you've probably moved on, but I've stumbled on your question and wanted to show that me n my team developed an annotation based java code generation library to remove the boilerplate from applying the decorator pattern. If you're interested you should check it out https://github.com/eyeem/decorator